# How to repeat a char in CString::Format

Tags: c++, mfc, repeat, format-specifiers

I need to repeat a char in CString::Format. Something like that in printf:

```
printf("%.*s",10, _T("-"));

result: ----------
```

How to realize this in CString::Format?

```
sOutput.Format(_T("%.*s"),10,_T("-")); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the appropriate CString constructor that does exactly that.

```
CString sOutput(_T('-'), 10);
```

and if you have to have it in `Format` as part of some larger string, then it's the same

```
CString sOutput;
sOutput.Format(L"Hello %s", CString(_T('-'), 10).GetString());
```

Comment: You should not pas CString without using GetString() to the Format function.

Comment: @xMRi Thanks. I sort of understand, and suspect you're right, do you mean the underlying char buffer could be left inconsistent? I thought the implicit LPCSTR cast would be used for the %s placeholder and the destructor of the temporary would clean up. Is that not the case?

Comment: @xMRi Sorry, I think I know what you mean, either to use GetString() with %s, or use %ls without GetString().

Comment: Either use CString(_T('-').GetString(), or a cast static_cast<LPCTSTR>(CString(_T('-')), Both are correct.

Comment: @acraig5075: `CString::Format` takes an **untyped** variable argument list. The compiler does not attempt to parse the format string, and emit calls to conversion operators where necessary. The arguments are passed as-is, and assumed to have the correct type. That's why variable argument lists are considered dangerous in C++ (although `CString` is implemented in a way where the common bug of passing the object vs. a pointer to the buffer is harmless).